# Insert multiple posts as parent of the first

Tags: wp-insert-post

I am trying to create some posts using the `wp_insert_post`. I want all the posts to be parent of the first.

I tried different approaches with no luck. Does anyone have any idea how this could be done?

```
foreach ( $books as $book ) {

  $post = array(
    'post_title'    => esc_html__( 'Post', 'book-cpt' ),
    'post_content' => 'test',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'book',
  );

  $book_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
$first_post = true;
$post_parent = 0;

foreach ( $books as $book ) {

  $post = array(
    'post_title'    => esc_html__( 'Post', 'book-cpt' ),
    'post_content' => 'test',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'book',
    'post_parent' => $post_parent
  );

  $book_id = wp_insert_post( $post );

  if ($first_post) {
    $post_parent = $book_id;
    $first_post = false;
  }    

};
```